# Translational invariance of sources/materials implies translational field invariance

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, physics, electromagnetism

Let's say we have an electromagnetic problem where $\epsilon = \epsilon(x,y)$, $\rho = \rho(x,y)$, and $J = J(x,y)$. The physicist argument is that by the symmetry of the problem we also have $E = E(x,y)$ and $H = H(x,y)$. However, I am a terrible physicist so usually arguments from symmetry are not obvious to me. Therefore I was trying to prove this from Maxwell's equations. Someone told me to take $\partial z$ of both sides of each equation.

Ok, so here was my attempt (assuming $\epsilon$ is scalar)...

$$ \nabla \cdot D = \rho$$
$$ \nabla \cdot \epsilon E = \rho$$
$$ \partial_z(\nabla \cdot \epsilon E) = 0$$
$$ \nabla \cdot \partial_z(\epsilon E) = 0$$
$$ \nabla \cdot \epsilon \partial_z E = 0$$
$$ \partial_x(\epsilon \partial_z E_x) + \partial_y(\epsilon \partial_z E_y) + \partial_z(\epsilon \partial_z E_z)= 0$$
$$ \partial_x(\epsilon \partial_z E_x) + \partial_y(\epsilon \partial_z E_y) + \epsilon \partial^2_z E_z= 0$$

Didn't see where to go so I tried Ampere's Law

$$ \nabla \times H = J + \partial_t D $$
$$ \partial_z (\nabla \times H) = \partial_t \partial_z D $$
$$ \nabla \times \partial_z H = \partial_t \partial_z \epsilon E $$
$$ \nabla \times \partial_z H = \partial_t (\epsilon \partial_z E) $$

Again, not clear to me how to conclude $d_zE = 0$.

In addition, I can think of a simple counter example to this symmetry argument. In empty space we have invariance in all directions. But, for any direction you choose I can form a plane wave traveling in that direction, so $E$ varies in that direction.

So when and how can we really conclude that translational invariance of sources/materials implies translational invariance of fields?

EDIT:(Attempting Mark's comment)

$$ \nabla \times (\nabla \times E) = -\partial_t \nabla \times B $$
$$ \nabla(\nabla \cdot E) - \nabla^2 E = -\mu (\partial_t J + \partial_t \epsilon E) $$
$$ \nabla(\nabla \cdot E) + \mu \partial_t J = \nabla^2 E - \mu \epsilon \partial_t E $$

so we get the three scalar equations

$$ \partial_x(\nabla \cdot E) + \mu \partial_t J_x = \nabla^2 E_x - \mu \epsilon \partial_t E_x $$
$$ \partial_y(\nabla \cdot E) + \mu \partial_t J_y = \nabla^2 E_y - \mu \epsilon \partial_t E_y $$
$$ \mu \partial_t J_z = \nabla^2 E_z - \mu \epsilon \partial_t E_z $$

Comment: The partial derivatives $\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial \vec H}{\partial z}$ satisfy the homogeneous wave equation (augmented to account for the inhomogeneous permittivity, $\varepsilon(x,y)$).  There will be non-trivial solutions (plane waves) for $\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial \vec H}{\partial z}$ unless one imposes conditions on the behavior of the fields away from the sources $\rho(x,y)$ and $\vec J(x,y)$.  Once doing so, one finds that $\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial z}=0$ and $\frac{\partial \vec H}{\partial z}=0$

Comment: @Mark Viola I made an edit. Does this look correct so far? I've never dealt with inhomogenous wave equations so I don't know how to proceed.